# arbitrary value for enum variable

Tags: c++, enums

There is this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
enum e  {zero,one};
void main()
{
    e num=(e)INT_MAX;
    std::cout<<num;
}
```

Is it defined by the standart that output will be 2147483647?(on condition sizeof(int)=4 bytes)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The answer is "no" by simple expedient that the standard does not guarantee that "int" is 32 bit. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar, ok. + if sizeof(int)=4byte

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX: the standard doesn't even guarantee that `sizeof(int) == 4` implies that `int` is 32 bit. But we know what you mean, "on condition that `INT_MAX` has value `2147483647`".

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX: That user name sucks, by the way. It's not too late to change it, to avoid confusion with "eXXXXXXXXXX" (who has been less than gentlemanly recently) and "eXXXXXXXXXXXX" (who owes me money).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; when converting an integer to an enumeration, the enumeration value is only specified if the integer value is within range. From the standard:

> 7.2/10 An expression of arithmetic or enumeration type can be converted to an enumeration type explicitly. The
>   value is unchanged if it is in the range of enumeration values of the enumeration type; otherwise the resulting
>   enumeration value is unspecified.

where the "range" is described in a rather complicated manner in 7.2/7, and essentially goes up to the smallest value of `2^M-1` that's no less than the largest defined value.

The compiler is allowed to use any integer type to represent the enumeration, as long as it's large enough to hold all the enumeration values; so in this case, it's free to use a smaller type than `int`, such as `char`. Also, `INT_MAX` is only guaranteed to be at least 32767.

Comment: `The value is unchanged if it is in the range of enumeration values` How can I define the range of enumeration values?

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX: All the possible values are declared in the enumeration's definition; that defines the range. In your case, you define `zero=0` and `one=1`, so the range is `[0,1]`, which can be represented by any type with at least one bit.

Comment: Where is this guaranteed : *INT_MAX is only guaranteed to be at least 32767*? There are some weird platforms where int is 9 bits

Comment: @VJovic: It's in the C standard, §5.2.4.2.1 (the C++ standard defers to it). If an implementation uses 9 bits for `int` then it's not a conforming implementation.

Comment: @VJovic: C99, 5.2.4.2.1 (and also Annex E) gives the minimum values for all the limits defined in `limits.h`. C++11 inherits these, as specified in 18.3.3/2. So on a platform with 9-bit words, `int` would have to be represented by two words.

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX That's wrong.  The range is guaranteed to be the smallest `2^n - 1` which is greater than or equal all of the enum values.  Thus, for `enum { one, two, three }`, the values are `0, 1 and 2`, but `3` is guaranteed to work as well.  (C++11 also allows explicitly specifying the underlying type, in which case, all values which fit into the underlying type are guaranteed.)

Comment: @James: in your example, `3` is not guaranteed to work - it's unspecified what the value will end up being in that case.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: No, James is correct; 7.2/7 specifies that values up to the next power of two are also in the range.

Comment: @James Kanze what about negative values of enumeration `enum { one=-2, two, three }` what is the range of this enumeration?

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX: Applying the rules in 7.2/7, and assuming 2s-complement arithmetic, the range for `{-2,-1,0}` would be `[-2,1]`, i.e. the range representable by a 2-bit signed integer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: and the reason that values up to the next power of 2 are valid is to support the use of enums as flag sets. `enum { foo = 1<<0, bar = 1<<1, baz = 1<<2}; // thank goodness, I don't have to list and name all 8 combinations of bits`. Arguably this means C enums are not really "enumerated types". Arguably no-one cares whether they are or not ;-)

Comment: How would `enum e : uint32_t {zero,one};` affect this? Is the full 32 bit range now defined? In practice, yes, but is it blessed by the standard(s)?

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no guarantee that `INT_MAX` is 2147483647. Second, there's no guarantee that your enum will have an underlying type capable of storing 2147483647, nor of storing whatever value `INT_MAX` is.

Now, if you want to know if you can use values for which there is no enumerator defined, then the answer is "yes". You can use values without a corresponding enumerator, as long as the value fits in the range of the the enum. The maximum value in this range is the smallest 2^n - 1 which is greater than or equal to all of the enumerators. In your case, the range is [0,1], so no other values can be used in a well-defined manner.

In the following code, the enum range is [0,3], so `3` is a valid value, even if there's no enumerator for it.

```
#include <iostream>

enum e  {zero,one,two};
void main()
{
    e num=(e)3;
    std::cout<<num; // will print "3"
}
```

The smallest value in the range is 0 if there are no enumerators with negative values. If there are enumerators with negative values, it depends on the representation used by the implementation. If the implementation uses two's complement, it's -(max+1), otherwise it's just -max. Basically, if there are negative values, the range has one more bit :)

```
#include <iostream>

enum e  {minus_one=-1,zero,one,two};
void main()
{
    e num=(e)-3;
    std::cout<<num; // will print "-3"
}
```

And in C++11 you can specify the underlying type explicitly, if you want to make sure a value will be representable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

enum e : std::int32_t {zero,one};
void main()
{
    e num=(e)2147483647;
    std::cout<<num; // will print "2147483647"
}
```

Comment: ``You can use values without a corresponding enumerator, as long as the value fits in the underlying type of the enum.'' That's incorrect, at least in C++03.  The max is `2^k - 1`, where `k` is the smallest value such that all enum values fit.

Comment: In your first example, `2` is not guaranteed to be printed (at least not for C++03 - I'll have to look up for C++11). The value stored into `num` is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any direct explenation in C++ specs, but can be easily deduced.
Underlying type of enum is compile-time defined. If compiler sees that `enum e` values easily fit in one byte it can decide to make it of type `char`.

That means you will not be able to store `INT_MAX` in this `enum`.

Comment: Paragraph 7.2.7 of C++ standard defines this.

Answer (score 0):

The range of valid enumeration values for an enumeration type is defined as follows in the C++ Working Draft, Section 7.2, paragraph 7:

**For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. Otherwise, for an enumeration where emin is the smallest enumerator and emax is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values in the range bmin to bmax, defined as follows: Let K be 1 for a two’s complement representation and 0 for a one’s complement or sign-magnitude representation. bmax is the smallest value greater than or equal to max(|emin| ? K, |emax|) and equal to 2^M ? 1, where M is a non-negative integer. bmin is zero if emin is non-negative and ?(bmax + K) otherwise. The size of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is max(M, 1) if bmin is zero and M + 1 otherwise. It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators. If the enumerator-list is empty, the values of the enumeration are as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.**

When converting an arithmetic or enumeration type to an enumeration type, the value is unchanged if it is in the range of enumeration values of the enumeration type. Otherwise, the value is *unspecified.*

To avoid unexpected behavior, the value being converted must be inside of the range of enumeration values. Furthermore, if it is necessary to check for out-of-range values dynamically, it must be done before the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

No. 2147483647 is out of range for this enumeration.

Enumeration's range, if there are no negative enumerations, is 0 to 2^k - 1, where 2^k is smallest power of 2 for which all enumerations are in range. In this case, that would be 2^1. Therefore any value greater then 2 for `e` makes the output undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The type of enum arg is integer.

```
enum e{zero, one}
```

means

```
int zero = 0; int one =1;
```

if you assign INT_MAX to a integer type arg.

the result is `2^31`

Comment: No, the underlying type can be any integer type large enough to hold all the values.